# Работа с цифрами c++

Tags: c++, арифметика

Помогите пожалуйста новичку. Нужно написать программу на C++, которая находит все двузначные числа, такие, что если к сумме цифр числа прибавить квадрат этой суммы, то получится само число.
Я пробовал написать, но у меня ничего не получилось.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 #include <cmath>
int main()
   {
   int j,n,summ; 
   cin >>  j,n;                    
for(n=10; n<=99; n+1)      
  {
    summ=(summ+n%10);
    j=(summ+(summ*summ));
        
  }
  if (j==n)
    cout <<j;
    
   
   getchar ();
   }
```

Comment: Что именно не получилось? Какие ошибки возникают? Также уточните заголовок. Используйте кнопку править

Comment: Попробуйте пойти с другой стороны (от цифр) `for (int up = 0; up < 10; up++) for (int low = 0; low < 10; low++) { int number = 10 * up + low; ... тут считаете сумму с квадратом и сравниваете ...` / (умножать быстрее чем делить и получать остаток)

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
    for(int m,s,n = 10; n <= 99; ++n)
    {
        m = n;
        for(s = 0; m; m/= 10) s += m%10;
        if (s + s*s == n) cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, лучше сначала решить уравнение относительно посследней цифры. Тогда для первой останется только три значения: 1, 4 и 9, т.к. первая цифра окажется под квадратным корнем.